# Correctly write a function of numpy meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The below code works. However, the line calculating rez is likely not written in the way intended by numpy developers. How can I rewrite it in an efficient way, without converting to and from lists?

Also, if you happen to know a good guide on how to write mathematical functions in python, which would work equally with numbers and np.arrays, please share :)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def L2normSquared(X, Y, x, y):
    return sum((X-x)**2 + (Y-y)**2)

X = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
Y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)

PX = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)
PY = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)
PXm, PYm = np.meshgrid(PX, PY)

rez = np.array([[L2normSquared(X, Y, x, y) for y in PY] for x in PX])

print(rez.shape)

plt.imshow(rez, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1])
plt.show()
```

**Edit**: Let me explain what I am trying to do

I generate 10 random points in 2D. Then I define a loss function for any arbitrary point (x,y) in 2D. Result of that function is the sum of euclidian distances of all 10 fixed points to this arbitrary point. Finally, I want to plot this loss function using 2d imshow method

**Edit 2**: According to Nils Werner's answer, one can use 3D arrays and broadcasting, producing the following code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def L2normSquared(X, Y, x, y):
    return np.sum((X-x)**2 + (Y-y)**2, axis=0)

X = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
Y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)

PX = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)
PY = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)
PXm, PYm = np.meshgrid(PX, PY)


rez = L2normSquared(X[:, None, None], Y[:, None, None], PXm, PYm)

print(rez.shape)

plt.imshow(rez, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1])
plt.show()
```

However, this code is actually slower than list comprehension (for 10000 random coordinates, step 0.01, it is roughly 2-3 times slower). For even larger inputs, there is a memory crash, which leads me to believe that this method internally results in 3D array dynamic programming, which does not scale well in terms of memory allocation.

**Edit 3**:
I am very sorry, but my minimal example was too minimal. In the original problem I am facing, the coordinates X and Y do not decouple to allow them to be calculated separately. One of the original functions is

```
def gaussian(X, Y, x, y):
  return sum(np.exp(-(X-x)**2 -(Y-y)**2))
```

Comment: I don't understand what operation you are trying to do here

Comment: Sorry, check edit

Comment: So, `X` and `Y` are 10 elems, but PX and PY are 10000?

Comment: Easy test: X,Y have 10 elements, PX, PY have steps 0.1 ;;;

Medium test: X,Y have 10000 elements, PX, PY have steps 0.1 ;;;

Hard test: X,Y have 10000 elements, PX, PY have steps 0.01 ;;;

List comprehension can do hard test

Comment: So, did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Ah sorry, I see there are updates I did not check yet. Let me give them a try

Comment: Bothering again - Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind `meshgrid` is that you get two or more arrays that you can simply pass into an operation themselves. So ideally, we wouldn't need a for loop at all.

But since you are doing an "outer difference" between `X` and `PX`, after which you summing over the `X` axis, you also need to use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to first do the outer product, and finally sum over the correct axis:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def L2normSquared(X, Y, x, y):
    return np.sum((X-x)**2 + (Y-y)**2, axis=0)

X = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
Y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)

PX = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)
PY = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)
PXm, PYm = np.meshgrid(PX, PY)

rez = L2normSquared(X[:, None, None], Y[:, None, None], PXm, PYm)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The output of this and original function is not the same. Columns seem mixed up

Comment: Ok, there is still a problem. For small amounts of data, your method is faster than mine, but for large amounts of data (10000 points, step 0.01) the method you suggest is 2x-3x slower than mine. Could it be  that you are creating 3D arrays, and memory allocation becomes an issue?

Comment: Yes, that might be the case.

Comment: As far as I know, a square of sums does not equal a sum of squares. I don't think it works in this case, and my actual use case is more complicated, I don't think it can be easily decomposed in this way

Comment: You are right, the results only *looked similar* :-)

Comment: An easy way to check is center of mass of a bunch of points. Your solution would give answer 0, but actual answer is a sum of distances. It can't be zero unless all points coincide

Answer (score 1):

A more systematic approach is to distinguish the sum from the norm, since your 
`L2normSquared` function can't see the particular roles of `x` vs `X`.

```
def normSquared(X, Y, x, y):
    return (X-x)**2 + (Y-y)**2

X = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
Y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
x = y = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)

rez=normSquared(*np.meshgrid(X,Y,x,y)).sum(axis=(0,1))
```

`normedSquared` understand arrays and numbers, it's  the `sum` wich is ambiguous here.

No need to reinvent `meshgrid`.

**EDIT**

To postpone memory problem, you can sum earlier, and se sparse meshes :

```
n=1000000
X = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
Y = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)

Xm,Ym,xm,ym = mesh = np.meshgrid(X,Y,x,y,sparse=True)

rez=((Xm-xm)**2).sum((0,1))+((Ym-ym)**2).sum((0,1))
```

This solves the problem in one second for n= 1,000,000 .

Comment: Your method crashes for 10000 random numbers with MemoryError, whereas list comprehension has no problem with that and even larger inputs. 4D arrays is a bad idea, there has to be something less memory-taxing

Comment: Hey B.M. thanks for the effort. It looks like my minimal example was too minimal. In my original problem the sum does not decouple, I just made it too easy. One of the original functions is sum(exp(-(X-x)**2 - (Y-y)**2))

Comment: For this case sum(exp(a+b)) = sum_XY (expa expb) = sum_X(expa) * sum_Y(expb). but for other cases your approach can be necessary, without big efficiency loss, since inner loops are vectored.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment.
I believe that your mathematical statement is not correct, as the product of two sums has interference terms (a+b)*(c+d)=a*c+a*d+b*c+b*d, whereas you only want the diagonal terms a*c+b*d

Comment: No interference here. `b=np.exp((Ym-ym)**2).sum(0)*np.exp((Xm-xm)**2).sum(1)` , 
 `a=np.exp((Xm-xm)**2 + (Ym-ym)**2).sum((0,1))` . `np.allclose(a,b)` is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `matrix-multiplication` magic with [`numpy.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for both memory efficiency and performance without messing around with `meshgrids`, like so -

```
a = np.exp(-(PX[:,None]-X)**2)
b = np.exp(-(PY[:,None]-Y)**2)
out = a.dot(b.T)
```

**Benchmarking**

Approaches and relevant functions -

```
def gaussian(X, Y, x, y):
  return sum(np.exp(-(X-x)**2 -(Y-y)**2))

def org_method(PX, X, PY, Y):
    PXm, PYm = np.meshgrid(PX, PY)
    return np.array([[gaussian(X, Y, x, y) for y in PY] for x in PX])

def matmult_method(PX, X, PY, Y):
    a = np.exp(-(PX[:,None]-X)**2)
    b = np.exp(-(PY[:,None]-Y)**2)
    return a.dot(b.T)
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [256]: X = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
     ...: Y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
     ...: 
     ...: PX = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.01)
     ...: PY = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.01)

In [257]: np.allclose(org_method(PX, X, PY, Y), matmult_method(PX, X, PY, Y))
Out[257]: True

In [258]: %timeit org_method(PX, X, PY, Y)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.76 s per loop

In [259]: %timeit matmult_method(PX, X, PY, Y)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop
```

Thus, we are getting a speedup of **`300x+`** there.

Comment: Hey Divakar, thanks for reply. I am sorry for having stated a problem that is significantly easier than the problem I have to solve. Please check Edit3 of my original post

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Think I have cracked it. Check out the updates.